# iterate through a lot of td to display barcode

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to go through a table and generate barcodes using jquery and jsbarcode https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode.

Ideally, the jquery would generate all barcodes and only display them if the user clicks on the [show/hide barcodes] button.

here's the html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"><a href="">38HY7</a></td>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>19.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"><a href="#">ABC123</a></td>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>29.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="barcodes">shwo barcodes</button>
```

Here's my jquery

```
$("#barcodes").click(function() {
  $(".code > a").each(function() {
    var thecode = $(".code a").text();
    $(this).append(
      "<div class='thebars'><br /><svg class='barcodes'></div></svg>"
    );
    $(".barcodes").JsBarcode(thecode, {
      displayValue: false,
      height: 20
    });
  });
});
```

At the moment, my script stores all codes in the var thecode but I want it to do it individually for each code and reset the var once the barcode is generated.

What if I have a large amount of codes to generate? What's the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're using common class names within your loop, so you're affecting all elements, instead of those within the current iteration.

To fix this you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current `a` within the `.code` container, then you need to find the `svg.barcodes` element in order to instantiate the `.JsBarcode()` library on it. Try this:

```js
$("#barcodes").click(function() {
  $(".code > a").each(function() {
    var thecode = $(this).text();
    var $bars = $('<div class="thebars"><br /><svg class="barcodes"></div></svg>').appendTo(this);
    $bars.find('.barcodes').JsBarcode(thecode, {
      displayValue: false,
      height: 20
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.8.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<button id="barcodes">Show barcodes</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"><a href="">38HY7</a></td>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>19.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"><a href="#">ABC123</a></td>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>29.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```